# Window Server send malicious attacks over the Internet

Tags: window

I hope someone can help me. I got some message that our server sends malicious attacks over the Internet. Sometimes RDP is not available over the internet. MAy you please give me a heads up where do I check which port is being used to send outgoing packets.

Regards,

Romeo

Comment: Try serverfault.com

Comment: sounds like [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/) is more the site you're looking for